# Iterating over hash prints hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm iterating over a bunch of nested hashes in Ruby with this:

```
@data.each do |key, value|
    puts "Key: #{key}"
    puts "Value: #{value}"
end
```

with the output:

```
Key: 1.0
Value: {"label"=>"Default Label"}
{"1.0"=>{"label"=>"Default Label"}}
```

Now I don't really understand why that last line is printed. It even gets printed when I remove the two "puts" calls from the loop.
I tried to find something about this behaviour online but couldn't find anything.
Any way I can prevent this from happening? Or am I misunderstanding the "each" call on the hash?

Comment: You must have a `puts` somewhere else.

Comment: are you in the REPL ?

Comment: @rohit89 I went through my code 10 times now, commenting out every single "puts" everywhere else outside what I really need and it's still showing up...

Comment: -1 Closed to vote as it cannot be reproduced under the assumption that "I shouldn't be in the REPL, no."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing this in the REPL.

The REPL, by default, returns (and prints) the value of the last statement executed.

In this case, it's `each`, which returns the collection it iterated over, so you see your original hash.

Comment: Just in case I'm not the only one unfamiliar with the term, "REPL", stands for ["Read, Eval, Print Loop"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). In Ruby, it generally refers to IRB or PRY.

Comment: I shouldn't be in the REPL, no. It's part of a script, running in Sublime text. Unless sublime text does funny stuff with it though.

And actually running the script from the Terminal does the same thing.

Comment: @AreusAstarte It's just not possible for there to be output if you're not creating any output. The only time you'll see output you're not explicitly calling for is if you're in the REPL or an equivalent environment. If you're really seeing this it should be trivial to duplicate in a standalone script you can post in its entirety.